# Using TagHelper in Custom TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm writing a simple pagination TagHelper, where I want the output to look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="...">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Some Other Text</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I had the idea that in defining my class I'd generate "a" elements, and decorate them with asp-controller, asp-action, etc., attributes, which would get rendered as the correct href link. Here's the code I came up with:

```
protected TagBuilder CreatePageLink( int page, bool enabled, string inner )
{
    TagBuilder a = new TagBuilder( "a" );

    a.MergeAttribute( "asp-controller", AspController );
    a.MergeAttribute( "asp-action", AspAction );
    a.MergeAttribute( "asp-route-page", page.ToString() );
    a.MergeAttribute( "asp-route-itemsPerPage", ItemsPerPage.ToString() );

    a.MergeAttribute( "title", $"goto page {page}" );

    if( !enabled ) a.AddCssClass( "disabled" );
    if( (page == Page) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(inner) ) a.AddCssClass( "active" );

    if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( inner ) ) inner = page.ToString();
    a.InnerHtml.AppendHtml( inner );

    TagBuilder li = new TagBuilder( "li" );
    li.InnerHtml.Append( a );

    return li;
}
```

But it doesn't work. The "MVC magic attributes" like asp-controller show up in the output, but the resulting links don't work. I have to add, in code, a specific href attribute to the embedded "a" element for the link to work.

How do I go about nesting TagHelpers, like the LinkTagHelper, inside my own custom TagHelper?

Comment: I'm not sure you can really "nest" tag helpers like that, but you could derive your class from `AnchorTagHelper` and integrate the base's generated output

Answer (score 2):

This video on tag helpers might be helpful: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Update-on-TagHelpers-with-Taylor-Mullen

Skip ahead to about 35 minutes in.

Also they put the code up on github: https://github.com/NTaylorMullen/WebCampsTV_TagHelpers1

The part that you will find relevant is [here](https://github.com/NTaylorMullen/WebCampsTV_TagHelpers1/blob/master/src/WebApplication70/ControllerNavigationTagHelper.cs):

```
[OutputElementHint("ul")]
public class ControllerNavigationTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public ControllerNavigationTagHelper(IUrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        UrlHelper = urlHelper;
    }

    private IUrlHelper UrlHelper { get; }

    public Type ControllerType { get; set; }

    public string Exclude { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "ul";

        var actionNames = ControllerType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods
            .Where(methodInfo => methodInfo.IsPublic)
            .Select(methodInfo => methodInfo.Name);

        var controllerName = ControllerType.Name;

        if (controllerName.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            controllerName = controllerName.Substring(0, controllerName.Length - "Controller".Length);
        }

        foreach (var name in actionNames)
        {
            if (!string.Equals(name, Exclude, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var displayName =
                    string.Equals(name, "Index", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? controllerName : name;
                output.PostContent.Append($"<li><a href='{UrlHelper.Action(name, controllerName)}'>{displayName}</a></li>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The basic premises is that there is an `IUrlHelper` service, I think built in to mvc (asp.net core mvc), that can be injected into your tag helper which you can use to construct the reference.

Once the `IUrlHelper` is injected you can use it to construct the url:

```cs
UrlHelper.Action(name, controllerName)
```